# How can I show categories only once in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem about showing `categories` only `once`. I wrote some codes to handle with this process but categories was shown as `twice`. I pointed out where the issue comes from.

How can I fix it?

Here is my html part which is shown below.

```
<div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Select one or more categories:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select class="form-control" th:field="*{categories}" multiple required
                        style="resize: vertical; height: 200px">
                    <th:block th:each="cat : ${listCategories}">
                    <option th:value="${cat.id}">[[${cat.name}]]</option>
                    </th:block>

                </select>
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Chosen categories:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div id="chosenCategories">
                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my js script code which is shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 
    moduleURL = "[[@{/brands}]]";
 
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        dropdownCategories = $("#categories");
        divChosenCategories = $("#chosenCategories");
 
        dropdownCategories.change(function() {
            divChosenCategories.empty();
            showChosenCategories();
        });
        
        showChosenCategories();  // ISSUE
    });
 
    function showChosenCategories() {
        dropdownCategories.children("option:selected").each(function() {
            selectedCategory = $(this);
            catId = selectedCategory.val();
            catName = selectedCategory.text().replace(/-/g, "");
 
            divChosenCategories.append("<span class='badge badge-secondary m-1'>" + catName + "</span>");
        });
 
    }
    
</script>
```

Comment: Is your issue that if you select, unselect and then select again a category, it will be shown twice? Or thrice if you do it again? and so on...

Comment: This edit doesn't make your issue any clearer. "showing categories" doesn't mean anything... please describe the expected result and what you're currently getting

Comment: @LaurentS.If there are 3 categories, it is listed as 3 categories and 3 same categories again and again. That's why I got 9 categories. When I select 2 categories, There are 4 categories listed. The process feels like this. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this code solve your problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

moduleURL = "[[@{/brands}]]";


$(document).ready(function() {
    dropdownCategories = $("#categories");
    divChosenCategories = $("#chosenCategories");

    dropdownCategories.change(function() {
        divChosenCategories.empty();
        showChosenCategories();
    });
    
    showChosenCategories();  // ISSUE
});

function showChosenCategories() {
    dropdownCategories.children("option:selected").each(function() {
        selectedCategory = $(this);
        catId = selectedCategory.val();
        catName = selectedCategory.text().replace(/-/g, "");
        $('#remove-'+catId).remove();
        divChosenCategories.append("<span id='remove-"+catId+"' class='badge badge-secondary m-1'>" + catName + "</span>");
    });

}
```

Comment: Yes even so you can replace your last line in your function by this
`$('#remove-span').last().remove();
        divChosenCategories.append("<span class='badge badge-secondary m-1' id='remove-span' >" + catName + "</span>");`

Comment: @AIASADWAIL I try it but it didn't work. If there are 3 categories, it is listed as 3 categories and 3 same categories again and again. That's why I got 9 categories. When I select 2 categories, There are 4 categories listed. The process feels like this. How can I solve it?